# R need function return list length 20 with names

Tags: r

Hey there I am super stuck on getting this example of r setup. I need a function called draw one number at a time (no duplicate numbers). Out put I want it to be a list with a length of 20 with each element a numeric scalar representing the randomly selected number.

Essentially I need the values to be something like: "draw1", "draw2", etc...

so far I have something like:

```
draw <- lapply(x=list(draw=1:80), FUN = sample, size 20, replace = F)
```

Comment: ps - I need it to not use a for loop?

Comment: `as.list(sample(1:80, size=20, replace=FALSE))`

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. You state that you *"need a function called draw"*; later you have `draw` as a `list`. So what is `draw` supposed to be: a `function` (of what?) or a `list`? Then you say that every element should be a `numeric` scalar but then you later mention values like `"draw1"`, `"draw2"` etc. Again, what are the elements supposed to be: `numeric` scalars or `character` strings? Please be precise in your problem description.

Comment: Hey there so this is supposed to represent a "Keno" game, 20 numbers are drawn at random. 
Yes the function should be called draw, one number at a time (that number can only be called once) the output of the draw function would be a list. Each character would be draw[random number].

The above example is me trying to figure this out, I have taking the draw=1:80 out and just had X as 1:80

Comment: I have tried the suggestion from Dan Y, it appears to be the right step forward.
I now need to mod each List object from just a number to concat Draw at the beginning of each entry

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I got what I needed if I am wrong I am wrong but. . .

```
draw <- function(){
     deal <- as.list(sample(1:80, size=20, replace=FALSE))
     names(deal) <- paste("draw", 1:20, sep="")
     return(deal)
}
```

Then by calling:

```
round.one <- draw()
round.one
```

I get a list of 20 entries each named Draw1, Draw2, Draw3, etc. . .

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand better what you're after here are some modifications/improvements

1. I'd make `draw` a function of the number of samples `n`; that way it's easy to draw different sample sizes.
2. You can use `setNames` to construct the `list` *and* give names to the `list` elements in one go.

Taken together we end up with

```
    draw <- function(n = 20) setNames(
        as.list(sample(1:80, size = n, replace = FALSE)),
        paste("draw", 1:n, sep=""))
```

Another useful function in this context is `replicate` which lets you replicate the process of drawing 20 samples `Nrep` times, storing results in a `matrix`

```
Nrep <- 10
mat <- replicate(Nrep, draw())
mat
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#draw1  39   71   18   55   55   26   70   24   30   24
#draw2  64   6    79   63   15   57   77   66   10   45
#draw3  59   36   39   64   42   20   68   33   61   27
#draw4  27   69   49   7    62   24   34   1    6    77
#draw5  62   54   1    13   24   53   15   4    60   17
#draw6  19   23   22   3    52   32   7    55   79   79
#draw7  44   44   73   18   58   64   44   6    58   31
#draw8  12   64   56   67   20   40   6    74   27   40
#draw9  13   33   5    1    49   73   38   46   45   59
#draw10 17   24   58   17   71   61   79   30   66   1
#draw11 56   40   9    12   39   27   4    31   8    48
#draw12 77   29   29   11   65   12   42   73   50   61
#draw13 76   57   64   45   79   13   54   19   11   28
#draw14 9    11   38   33   16   58   41   54   18   60
#draw15 66   74   76   46   32   23   2    7    52   54
#draw16 50   1    63   19   30   51   26   18   39   4
#draw17 20   21   50   79   51   5    75   9    7    69
#draw18 2    60   6    65   1    16   66   42   75   32
#draw19 43   65   23   73   47   63   53   61   44   74
#draw20 69   5    30   5    64   77   20   13   17   13
```

It's now easy to operate on the `matrix` in a row (`apply(mat, 1, ...)`) or column-wise way (`apply(mat, 2, ...)`).